# How to return a new dictionary with a value added?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I'm playing around with functional stuff in swift. I'm trying to create an accumulator function for `reduce`, which should start with a dictionary, and return a new dictionary with the value added.

Basically this, but with `current` being immutable. I have to return a new dictionary equivalent to what it would be if I did the following:

```
func newDictionaryWithValueAdded(current:Dictionary<Int, Double>, amount: Int) -> Dictionary<Int, Double> {
    // current[amount] = amount/100
    // return amount
}
```

Is there a function for that? Something similar to array concantenation?

Comment: Also is this approach too slow? It's pretty standard for other immutable-focused functional languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a function parameter as *variable* with `var`.
In the following example, `current` is a copy of the passed dictionary (because
dictionaries are value types), but can be modified in the function:

```
func newDictionaryWithValueAdded(var current:Dictionary<Int, Double>, amount: Int) -> Dictionary<Int, Double> {
    current[amount] = Double(amount)/100
    return current
}

let dict1 : [Int : Double] = [:]
let dict2 = newDictionaryWithValueAdded(dict1, 12)

println(dict1) // [:]
println(dict2) // [12: 0.12]
```